# Do Legacy XP Bonus unlocks affect Legacy XP?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In the game, there are character perks that allow you to unlock XP Bonuses for different activities in the game, such as Space Combat, PvP, Flashpoints and a lot of other events.

[image: Screenshot of the unlock system]

But do those also affect Legacy XP? Is Legacy XP always a percentage of the XP gained or a set value? In short, are those unlocks beneficial when you hit the level cap?

Comment: Quests have the rewards listed in the bottom of the Mission Log Window, does it list Legacy XP?  If not can you check a 50 and 55 since one the two might give you another UI there.

Comment: @MatthewRead No does not list Legacy XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because Legacy XP is affected by the XP's source too, it's not just generalized as "experience." so if you have 25% more xp on quest rewards, the legacy system will calculate the buffed xp received.